# Plugin intercom update to latest version cordova error at build/run

Tags: android, cordova, intercom

I want to update plugin intercom to latest version. I am using cordova version 9.0.0
For iOS works fine, but to update intercom for android I must have the version of platform >= 9.0.0
I updated from version 7.1.1 to 9.0.0 (android platform), but I got 2 errors. I think that is gradle cause these errors... Because I tried to make another fresh cordova project to see if everything works fine... but application does not run/build.

The text of errors:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
```

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '..\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-intercom\be-intercom.gradle' line: 46
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Could not find method execute() for arguments [] on task ':app:copyGoogleServices' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

I have google-services.json (in root).
Everything works fine before this update.

In ***..\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-intercom\be-intercom.gradle*** at line 46 is `tasks.copyGoogleServices.execute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to replace the execute() with finalizedBy() in platforms\android\cordova-plugin-intercom\be-intercom.gradle and to copy google-services.json in platforms\android\app.
https://medium.com/@olku/gradle-5-0-broken-api-of-the-exec-task-5b2d76c8d121